# Yii combobox validation

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, validation

I am developing with Yii framework

This is a part of my View

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('codCity', '',$cityList);
```

the dropdown is filled up so that in the end, option are something like that

```
<option value="XX">(Select a city)</option>
<option value="RM">Rome</option>
<option value="FL">Florence</option>
...
```

from a validation viewpoint, the first option (XX) is not valid, while the others are valid
so in my model I have

```
public function rules()
{
        return array(
            ...
            array('codCity', 'compare', 'operator'=>'!=', 'compareValue'=>'XX' ,
                  'message'=>'please select a city'),
            ...
    );
}
```

and this is the only validation rule that I apply to codCity field.

Unluckily, things are not going as I suppose, and all options are validated as 'good', even the bad one (XX)

any suggestions?

thank you so much

Comment: Do you do client-side validation? If yes, what does not work exactly? Server-side? Client-side? Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail

You can specfiy a `prompt` option.

> prompt: string, specifies the prompt text shown as the first list option. Its value is empty. Note, the prompt text will NOT be HTML-encoded.